# Apps Script timed based trigger for script not executing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to execute a script (Apps Script) which counts rows in a google spreadsheet and, every time it executes it counts and write in Y2 the number of rows, and the difference between every execution in Y3.

If there are any rows sends and email to the specified email.

I don't want this to be on edit, since it would flood my email with several alerts, but to make a summary of new rows in the document every day (I have tried executing it every 5minutes for the test).

The thing is when I execute my code manually it does what it has to do, but not when it's called by the time based trigger.

Here is the code:

```
function counting() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var lastNumRows = sheet.getRange("Y2").getValue();
  var diff = numRows - lastNumRows;
  sheet.getRange("Y2").setValue(numRows);
  sheet.getRange("Y3").setValue(diff);
 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("Y3");
  var value = cell.getValue();
  
  if (value > 0) {
    var recipient = "email";
    var subject = "Y3 Content";
    var body = "Content is " + value;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Any other solution that sends an email with new rows everyday to an specified email by me would make me happy.

EDIT:
Regarding the information asked:

This is the trigger execution:
[image]

And this is the trigger configuration:

[image]

No log returns an error and the execution is supposedly completed, yet no new values in cells Y2 or Y3 and no email, even after adding or removing some rows

Comment: Could you add to your question a screenshot of the trigger details (Triggers -> Edit trigger)? Also, have you checked the execution logs to see if there is any failed execution originating from that trigger (a screenshot of that would be helpful to)?

Comment: @BryanMonterrosa I added it to the post

Comment: Unfortunately it's in spanish.  Do you have more than one function named counting

Comment: Add some logging to log or console in your script after each step so when you review the execution details you can get more info about what actually took place. Example, log the critical variable values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getActiveSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) gets the sheet that is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI. Perhaps that is the  problem.

Try using [`getSheetByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to see if that resolves the issue.

#### Use

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

#### Instead of

```
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: This was it. It seems it was trying to use an old one with sheet id 1, instead of the only sheet there is in the document, which id is not 1